# Metro UI CSS Rating component

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit, rating, metro-ui-css

I'm using ajax toolkit rating control in my aplication. Application is made in asp.net web forms. Now I need to change design of aplication in Metro. I'm using Metro UI CSS and I'm having trouble with rating control.

With ajax I used this code in code behind to save rate in database:

```
protected void Rating_Changed(object sender, RatingEventArgs e)
{
int rowIndex = ((sender as Rating).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).RowIndex;    
int accommodationId = Convert.ToInt32(gvAccommodations.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value);

        var context = new RezervacijaSmjestajaDbContext();
        var accommodation =
                 (
                    from a in context.Accommodations.ToList()
                    where a.Id == accommodationId
                    select a
                  )
                    .Single();

        accommodation.BrojOcjena++;
        double NovaOcjena = Convert.ToDouble(e.Value);
        accommodation.ZbrojOcjena = accommodation.ZbrojOcjena + NovaOcjena;
        accommodation.Rating = accommodation.ZbrojOcjena / accommodation.BrojOcjena;

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

How do I save rates in database if I use Metro UI CSS rating control?

Answer (score 0):

[Metro UI rating widget](http://metroui.org.ua/rating.html) having onRate event callback option.

```
 <div class="rating" data-role="rating"  data-on-rate="func_onRate"></div>

    function func_onRate(value, star, widget){
            // do your ajax here to save changed rating 
    }
```